# JSX: Sorting objects alphabetically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sorting

I have two functions that look like this:

```
  const compare = (direction: string) => {
    const alphabetize = (a, b) => {
      if (direction === "alpha") {
        if (a.name < b.name) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.name > b.name) {
          return 1;
        }
      } else if (direction === "reverseAlpha") {
        if (a.name > b.name) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (a.name < b.name) {
          return 1;
        }
      }
      return 0;
    };
  };

  const sortAlphabetically = () => {
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      items: items.sort(compare("alpha"))
    }));
  };
```

I need to be able to pass a string into the `compare` function somehow, that tells it which way to sort the letters (alphabetically, or reverse alphabetically).

But this method doesn't work, because `alphabetize` is never called this way. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you forgot `return alphabetize;` at the end of `compare`

Comment: `return alphabetize = () => {}`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava — No! That will create an implicit global (or throw an exception if in strict mode)

Comment: @RobinZigmond is absolutely right.  Also, you can reduce the amount of code significantly by only implementing ascending sort, capturing the result, and if descending was asked for, multiply the result by `-1`.

Comment: ah thank you so much for your helpful feedback and suggestions -- yes that worked perfectly! I did have it there initially, but was calling it wrong at first

Comment: Also, if you want to follow the best practices, the proper way to type the function would be `const compare = (direction: 'alpha' | 'reverseAlpha') => {`. Then, if you make a sneaky typo like `compare('revesreAlpha')`, the type system will catch it for you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this short solution:

```js
const data = ['zoo', 'river', 'dimond', 'man', 'football', 'hot'];

// Keep the data array for another sort, as sort changes the original array. You can perform this to the `data` array too. This also gives you the same result.  
const clone = [...data];

const compare = (direction) => {
    if (direction === 'asc') {
 return (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1;
    } else if (direction === 'desc') {
 return (a, b) => b > a ? 1 : -1;
    }
}


console.log('Asc order: ', data.sort(compare('asc')));
console.log('Desc order: ', clone.sort(compare('desc')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: thank you! is there a reason you put `console.log('Asc order: ', data.sort(compare('asc')));` rather than `console.log('Asc order: ', clone.sort(compare('asc')));?` Wouldn't that mutate the original array?

Comment: I cannot get you. Could you please describe?

Comment: you said `.sort` changes the original array, which is `data` in your example. Then you copied the elements of `data` into `clone`. So did you mean to have `clone.sort(compare('asc')));?` in your first `console.log` statement? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Actually, first I declare the ```data``` array then copy the data into a new array ```clone```, then I sort the ```data``` array which sorts the data array but I copy the original data before performing the sort operation. So ```data.sort``` doesn't affect the ```clone``` array.

Comment: oh, I think that makes sense now -- thanks for such a short and elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

[edit] You must call alphabetize inside of the compare function like so:

```
const compare = () => {
  const alphabetize = () => {
   ...stuff
  }
alphabetize()
}
```

And a side note:
JS Comes with a sort and a reverse function:

```
  var sortAlphabets = (text, direction) =>
    direction === "reverseAlpha"
      ? text
          .split("")
          .sort()
          .reverse("")
          .join("")
      : text
          .split("")
          .sort()
          .join("");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). You code will look like this.

```js
const sortAlphabetically = () => {
    setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      items: items.sort((a,b)=>( sort === 'alpha' ? a.localeCompare(b) : -1*a.localeCompare(b))
    }));
  };
```

Please let me know if I missed anything.